# Decision Tree on Unbalanced Data

Tags: machine-learning, r, decision-trees, class-imbalance

While running decision tree, I have unbalanced data. The data balance is 93%(Class 0) to 7% (Class 1).

Now when I am plotting decision tree to understand the factors contributing to class 1, then I find that most boxes are for 0 class (as it is 97% of the data).

Also, after pruning, very few contributors are there which are contributing to class 1. How can I get the factors contributing to class 1?

Answer (score 1):

Which function are you using at Loss? Using the right one is important when dealing with imbalanced datasets. 7% is imbalanced, but not that bad.

Have you tried any eXplainable Artificial Intelligence (XAI) method? Normally I use Shap.
It is really good to see which feature contributes in which direction. You can see an example here.
[image: Shap interpretation]

- You can check the [github here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap)
- You can check the [paper here](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/7062-a-unified-approach-to-interpreting-model-predictions)

Comment: Thanks, do you know equivalent package of "Shap" in R ?

Comment: Also i am anticipating that Shap results will also be biased to class 0 and will show important variables contributing to 0 detection. Here i am more interested in knowing variables contributing to 1.

Comment: About R, I dont know, there has to be something for sure. How about this https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/iml/versions/0.9.0/topics/Shapley?

Comment: Check this link for dealing with imbalanced dataset, but for your case choosing the right metric should be okey https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/7-techniques-handle-imbalanced-data.html